# Aggregation query performance and improvement on dataset < 1M

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I am using the MongoDB's aggregation framework and are performing queries on a collection which currently contains about 700K documents. Here is the query:

```
    db.logs.aggregate(
    {'$match' : { 'tag' : 'TAG-XYZ' }},
    {'$project' : {
      'tag' : '$common_tag.bId'
    }},
    {'$unwind' : '$tag'},
    {'$group' : {
      '_id' : '$tag',
      'total' : {'$sum' : 1}
    }},
    {'$sort':{'_id':1}},
    {'$skip':0},
    {'$limit':20}
    )
```

`logs` contain about 20 fields. `tag` is an array of an average of 10 tags and `common_tag` is just an embedded document which keeps some categorized tags separated from the tag array to eliminate the use of an initial `$unwind` of `tag`. I use pagination so the value of `skip` is variable. Note that querying is used so there is no set of fixed results.

The thing is that the query takes at least 30 seconds to execute. My worry is the dataset keeps growing and it may not support my real-time (or near-real-time) query requirements. Is there a better way to improve the query?

Comment: why do you have `$match` twice? and if `$skip: 0` then don't bother including it

Comment: Do you have an index on `tag`?  Also, the second match isn't needed because of the `$unwind` on the same field that you're checking isn't empty.

Comment: Yes I do have an index on `tag`. I use pagination so `skip` and `limit` values are not constant. I don't know but when I removed the second match, the time ranges from around 20 to 30 seconds still.

Comment: Updated aggregation query as suggested and included additional info.

Comment: I've read about foreign data wrappers, so I am thinking if it is feasible to use provided that aggregating such amount of data is really a bottleneck.