# Aggregation framework on full table scan

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I know that aggregation framework is suitable if there is an initial `$match` pipeline to limit the collection to be aggregated. However, there may be times that the filtered collection may still be large, say around 2 million and the aggregation will involve `$group`. Is the aggregation framework fit to work on such a collection given a requirement to output results in at most 5 seconds. Currently I work on a single node. By performing the aggregation on a shard set, will there be a significant improvement in the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only limitations are that the result of the aggregation can't surpass the limit of 16MB, since what it returns is a document and that's the limit size for a document in MongoDB. Also you can't use more than 10% of the total memory of the machine, for that usually $match phases are used to reduce the set you work with, or a $project phase to reduce the data per document.

Be aware that in a sharded environment after $group or $sort phases the aggregation is brought back to the MongoS before sending it to the next phase of the pipeline. Potentially the MongoS could be running in the same machine as your application and could hurt your application performance if not handled correctly.

Comment: OK, so it can handle such amount of data. But from what I have encountered so far, when the collection the aggregation is performed to contains so much data, the performance degrades. I have this issue in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887626/aggregation-query-performance-and-improvement-on-dataset-1m). It seems a limitation in some way.

Comment: Indeed it does, after all it has to scan all that data. That's another reason besides the size limitation to reduce the amount of data with $match or $project. If you are using shards the data scanned will be only the subset that it's stored in the shard and therefore it will be an improvement in performance since it doesn't scan the whole collection.

Comment: It does look expensive though, if I have 5 million documents to aggregate, it appears I need to setup a number of shards to obtain a result in real time. :(

Comment: Do you have indexes properly created? as you can see here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes there are several aggregation phases that can take advantage of indexes. 5 million documents shouldn't be a problem if you make a good use of indexes.

Comment: Yes, I do have index on the field used for `$match`, but again the resulting output is still large (think 2M apples in a fruit basket of 5M). It appears, the subsequent operations like `$group` may be the bottleneck. If I have a 4G RAM, is that enough to handle the pipeline operations?

Comment: It largely depends on the size of the documents, in order to be effective the whole index must be in memory. If the collection is too large it's possible that the memory is not enough and the indexes are not improving the performance. $group indeed can be quite costly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24956/discussion-between-nyde1319-and-lgomezma)